# How To Set the Text of an item in ListView

Tags: android

I have a list of ListItems's in my listview. The ListItem has a name instance variable. I am trying to get the text of each of the items just to be the name.

How can I do this?

```
 public class List extends ListActivity  {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<ListItem>(this, R.layout.list_item, Previousclass.LinkedList-from-previous-class));
```

Right now it is just displaying the memory location of each item i.e. ListItem@47234c10

Comment: for printing the list? That is all I am using. I have nothing else. In the previous class I am just fetching the data and putting the data in the necessary fields in the ListItem object. Then with this I am just passing the LinkedList into the adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extend `ArrayAdapter` to implement `getView()`.  The `ArrayAdapter` implementation is returning the `toString()` value of your `ListItem` object.

Or alternatively stringify your data before adding it to the adapter.

Comment: Do you think you could potentially elaborate on the first option?

Comment: There's plenty of examples on google, like: http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/using-arrayadapter-and-listview-in-android-applications

Answer (score 1):

What is `Previousclass.LinkedList-from-previous-class` ? Is it a list of your items?

If yes,
Your list of items should be a list of names of items. Your resulting screen should have listview in it and the adapter you created should be used this way

```
result.setListAdapter(Youradapter)
```

I am just giving you sample based on what code you have posted. If you need details, please elaborate your code.

```
result.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<ListItem>(this, R.layout.list_item, Previousclass.LinkedList-from-previous-class))
```

Comment: yes. Previousclass is the class that I created the linkedlist in

Comment: what is result supposed to be in this case?